# vim - navigate simultaneously through multiple files with timestamps

Tags: vim, timestamp

I often have to deal with reading two or three files with logs. The logs are produced by different processes and have different levels of verbosity (thus different number of lines), but lines in all of them start with a timestamp.

I thought about writing some vim script, that would allow me to open those files simultaneously, and then automatically navigate via timestamp - i.e. when moving down in one file, the other ones will be centered on lines with relevant timestamp.

Does anyone have any ideas about the realization of such task? Any suggestions about commands and tricks that could be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implemented such in my [LogViewer plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4156); hopefully it'll suit your needs.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [ingo-karkat.de](http://ingo-karkat.de/swdev/vim/LogViewer.png))</sub>